# Method not found but method is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have added an additional view to one of my objects, as well as a corresponding method and route, yet I cannot load the view:

```
NoMethodError in Scans#parse

Showing J:/code/vsdb/app/views/scans/parse.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `parse' for #<Scan:0x23b0590>
Extracted source (around line #18):

15: 
16:   <div class="field">
17:     <%= s.label :parse %><br />
18:     <%= s.text_field :parse %>
19:   </div>
20: <% end -%>
```

Here is the method in the Scan controller. The method is there, so I don't understand what the error message is really complaining about. I tried restarting the server. I'm planning on doing more with this method, I just want it to show the view for now.

```
def parse
  @scan = Scan.new
end
```

Comment: The form is looking for a model attribute called `parse` on your Scan model. Not sure what you trying to do, but for this to work you have to add a database column `parse` to your `scans` table.

Comment: *Here is the method in the Scan controller* -- it must be in you MODEL, not in the controller!

Answer (score 1):

The error is complaining about parse not being a method of your Scan model (not your controller). In this context parse will be a method defined automatically by Rails for one of Scan's attributes but in this case it's missing.

If you have added an attribute called parse to Scan using a migration you might need to run rake db:migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, Rails views cannot access controllers. If you have a controller method that needs calling you should do it in the action before passing control off to the view.

In your case you have a variable called `@scan` which is an instance of the `Scan` class. This is where the view is trying to find the method.

As pointed out in the comments, you can get around this restriction by declaring specific methods as 'helper' methods, which exposes them to the view.

```
ScanController < ApplicationController

  helper_method :parse

  def parse
    @scan = Scan.new
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: *Rails views cannot access controllers* unless you called `helper_method` on one of its methods.